# iTunes not syncing TV Shows bought on Store to iPod Touch 4G with 5.x

Tags: mac, itunes, ipod

Syncing with iTunes 10.5.2 on a Mac; I selected the shows (Season 2 of Modern Family) and tried to sync, but it only started copying an episode of Psych. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the videos section of the ipod sync screen.  Then check the box that says something like "Sync Videos".  Then go and check all the videos you want synced to your ipod.

If this fails, then go onto the video section of itunes (not the sync video section), then select the episode(s) you want to sync to your ipod, and select Advanced from the top of the screen.  From that menu, there should be something that starts with "Convert".  Select it, and then repeat from the top of this post.

Comment: none of these worked :-/

Comment: Hmmm, not really sure then.  Sorry!  :-(

Comment: No problem, no downvote.